# Newbie : installing and upgrading python module

Tags: python

I have downloaded and install a python library, via setup.py , python2.5 setup.py install ...

now the version is changed at the source . a newer library is available. originally , i have clone it via mercurial, and install it. right now , i have updated repository.

how do i use the newer version ? overwrite the installation ?

by simply doing setup.py install again ?

Comment: Any specific reason you are installing Python from source? Why not use pre-packaged binaries?

Comment: I am using Ubuntu 10.04 which shipped with python 2.6 while I need to use python 2.5, so I have everything manually compiled and installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, just do `setup.py install` again.